# Get Color using integer

Tags: java, colors, integer

The title is a bit confusing but I want to add an integer to a color method. I mean if I had three Colors and want to go through them with a for loop (Something like that below):

```
Color color1 = something;
Color color2 = something;
Color color3 = something;

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    int r = color(i).getRed();
    int g = color(i).getGreen();
    int b = color(i).getBlue();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question... but your loop does look very strange. It won't do anything since 1 > 4 is false in the very first iteration.

Comment: @Steve my mistake. I want that the first color (color1) will be used in the first execute of the loop and the second color (color2) in the second loop etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the three colors in an array and access that array inside your loop.

```
// take these three colors for example
Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW};

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    int r = colors[i].getRed();
    int g = colors[i].getGreen();
    int b = colors[i].getBlue();
}
```

Comment: Why iterate through the loop 3 times?